# Trouble Aligning Text in Flexbox divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-align

I'm trying to convert my resume to HTML, and ran into an issue with displaying the text the way I want.

Here is an image from my resume with tables drawn so you can see how the text is aligned

[image]

Here is how my HTML currently looks (I have padding and border to simulate table lines but will remove those later)

[image]

I've tried giving specific classes to the divs I want to be positioned and using align-self or text-align, and have not been successful.

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.info {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-right: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="info address"> Address </div>
  <div class="info contact"> Phone:</div>
  <div class="info"> (123) 456 7890 </div>
  <div class="info address"> Zip Code </div>
  <div class="info contact"> Email:</div>
  <div class="info"> email@domain.com </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is tabular-data. As such a table is appropiate and would be the right thing to use. Alternativly a CSS-Grid would also solve this.

Comment: because you are using `padding-right: 500px;` and `padding-bottom: 30px;`. this creates space **not** for content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution without tables, using `flex-wrap: wrap` for the container, percentage `width`-values for the flex children and certain pseudo-selectors for those to have the same thickness of border everywhere, omitting adjacent /double borders (creating a table-like design).

You can add padding right/left to create additional distance between borders and text.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.info {
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.info:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
}

.info:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

.contact {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="info address">Address</div>
  <div class="info contact">Phone:</div>
  <div class="info">(123) 456 7890</div>
  <div class="info address">Zip Code</div>
  <div class="info contact">Email:</div>
  <div class="info">email@domain.com</div>
</div>
```

Acutally I am not sure if you actually want the borders to be visible. If not, it gets a lot simpler:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.info {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.contact {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="info address">Address</div>
  <div class="info contact">Phone:</div>
  <div class="info">(123) 456 7890</div>
  <div class="info address">Zip Code</div>
  <div class="info contact">Email:</div>
  <div class="info">email@domain.com</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  max-width: 33.3333%;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.contact {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="info address"> Address </div>
  <div class="info contact"> Phone:</div>
  <div class="info"> (123) 456 7890 </div>
  <div class="info address"> Zip Code </div>
  <div class="info contact"> Email:</div>
  <div class="info"> email@domain.com </div>
</div>
```

Not that neat. But if you still want to use flex box. this might help.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the structure of rows in your html and use `flex-grow` instead of `justify-content`

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/fredklein/q79Lhp3z/4/

I have also removed the 500px padding which prevents hinders the flex layout.

My favorite reference to css flex at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.info {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="info address"> Address </div>
    <div class="info contact"> Phone:</div>
    <div class="info"> (123) 456 7890 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="info address"> Zip Code </div>
    <div class="info contact"> Email:</div>
    <div class="info"> email@domain.com </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simulating a table you could actually use a table.
I don’t have my computer at the moment so I will do my best with my phone.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>123 ln street</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Me@domain.ext</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: he already uses a table (*Here is an image from my resume with tables drawn so you can see how the text is aligned*) but wants to convert them into a flexbox. That it is fine to use a table in his case could have been stated as a comment not as an answer (or simply upvote the exsisting comment). As such you miss the actual question and not telling the OP something he doesn't already know how to do.

Comment: I think this is not what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

like I wrote in the comments. This is not a task for Flexbox as yyou have tabular-data. As such you also should use a `table` which is completely fine and appropiate in your case.

As you insist though on using Flexbox I have a solution for you. All you need to do is to give boxes a width of `100% / 3` using the `calc-function` and remove the `justify-content` property. If you use a `border` or `padding`, you also have to use the `box-sizing: border-box` property to ensure a correct calculation.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.info {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="info address"> Address </div>
  <div class="info contact"> Phone:</div>
  <div class="info"> (123) 456 7890 </div>
  <div class="info address"> Zip Code </div>
  <div class="info contact"> Email:</div>
  <div class="info"> email@domain.com </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove some properties such:

```
justify-content: space-between;
padding-right: 500px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

**Header** of information with class `contact`:

- with `width: 13%` & `text-align: right`

**Content:** of information with class `info`:

- `width: 69%` & `padding: 8px;`

---

Clean example with tableless:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.info {
  width: 69%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contact {
  width: 13%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Christopher Williamson</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="info address contact"> Address:</div>
  <div class="info">Stack Street, 26</div>
  <div class="info contact"> Phone:</div>
  <div class="info">(123) 456 7890 </div>
  <div class="info address contact"> Zip Code:</div>
  <div class="info">456-7890</div>
  <div class="info contact">Email:</div>
  <div class="info">email@domain.com</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the width of the divs as a calc function 33.33% - margins

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: if yous eta  width of 33.33% then you dont need to sue a calc-function. If you use a calc-function then you have to use `100% / 3` which you also should do to prevent possible pixel inaccurcy on high-resolution displays. It however misses the most important info to prevent issues when using a border like in the OP`s case or if he adds a padding. Also you could have edited your previose answer with that.